# Grid doesn't show any data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, extjs, grid

```
 var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                root:           'details',
                fields: ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7'],
                pruneModifiedRecords:true,
                autoload:       false
         });


         var gridDetail = new Ext.grid.Panel({
             title: 'Details',
             store: store,
             width : '100%',
             header: {
               titleAlign: 'center'
             },
             columns: [
                    { text: 'col1',  dataIndex: 'a1' },
                    { text: 'col2', dataIndex: 'a2'},
                    { text: 'col3', dataIndex: 'a3' },
                    { text: 'col4', dataIndex: 'a4' },
                    { text: 'col5', dataIndex: 'a5' },
                    { text: 'col6', dataIndex: 'a6' },
                    { text: 'col7', dataIndex: 'a7' },

                ],               
         });
```

These are my configures about store and grid. I load the data via an ajax request;

```
var getInfo= function (s1,s2,s3){
            gridDetail.mask('Loading'); 
             Ext.Ajax.request({                  
               url : '../project/getInfo.ajax',
               params :{
                   s1: s1,
                   s2: s2,
                   s3: s3
               },
               callback: function(options, success, response){

                        if(success){
                         var resp = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            gridDetail.unmask();

//some other codes not related grid

                            store.loadData(resp,false);
                        } else {
                            gridDetail.unmask();
                            Alert(resp.msj);
                        }
                 }

           });
```

and my return JSON is ;

{"success":true,"first":[{...},],"details":[{"a1":"d1","a2":"d2",..."a7":"d7"}]}

But after all this nothing shown on grid, and no error returns. Everything is okay but nothing happen in grid. Mask shown and then unshown but no data shown on grid.

What is my problem, i can't see it? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try `store.loadData(resp.details);`

Comment: The real question: Why are you firing off a separate Ajax request? Just let the store handle it.

Comment: Because @EvanTrimboli i don't load store only. I do a lot of work in my request.

Comment: @CD.. I tried that yesterday, it didn't work but now it works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems good for me. Maybe something with the data format.

Add a listeners to your store to check what kind of records the store get.

> ```
> listeners:{
>      load: function( this, records, options ) {
>         console.log(records);
>      }
> }
> ```